# Extract data from to connected Excel files, as if one is function and the other its parameter values

Tags: matlab, xlsread

My question has 2 parts.

Part 1:

I have 3 Excel files each with multiple sheets. I have loaded all files with sheets into the matlab using a small code. The files are loaded in a structured form. i.e. One main structure and 3 files as a seperate fields  with multiple sheets as a value.

Part 2:

Now I have another seperate excel file having a single sheet with a single column.  The col of this excel file has entries(or values/names) which are linked to each file of part one. In other words each excel file of part 1 is a data of each entry of a column of excel file in part 2.

Now my problem is that I want to link both of them. This is important because in further processes I want my program to run in a way that when I specify the value or tell the entry from excel file of part 2 it takes corresponding data from excel file of part 1.  Is there any way of doing it?

This block diagram may be helpful to understand what I mean. [BLock Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDq8e.png)

Comment: have you loaded the sheet-names into a structure or the entire values of all sheets in separate fields of the structure? What have you tried? I think there are several ways to solve your problem, but it's hard to say which might be the best in your case.

Comment: @bushmills. I have loaded all excel files of part 1 with their names. e.g. main_structure ----> excel_file_name------>value. Here excel_file_name is a cell which contains multiple sheets of each excel file.